# VSC on Mac Console.Readline() debug problems: Can't input in console

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**I am trying out VSC .NET C# development over Visual Studio on Mac.**

With the C# DevKit.

I have tried all the advises I could find but I can't get any console input to work in debug mode.
The simple code below does not show up in the debug console at all and if I use `Console.WriteLine("Name: ");`the debug console shows the outputted text but no input is possible.

```
Console.Write("Name: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
System.Console.WriteLine(name);
```

In `launch.json` I changed the terminal to `"integratedTerminal"` . I did try every option possible.

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
```

In `settings.json`I added "external" and "Terminal.app":

```
"editor.fontSize": 12,
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app",
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {},
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

**EXTENSIONS installed**
I have among others:

- C# Dev Kit from MS
- C# from MS
- .NET Extension Pack from MS
- .NET Runtime Install Tool from MS

**Anybody having a fix that works for input in Debug mode VSC on Mac for .NET C# projects?**

I tried every advise I could find. And everything described above.

Comment: Are you creating a console application?